# Using MSBuild 4.0, passing property name to be expanded in c# project file from MSBuild task, how?

Tags: c#, msbuild

I created a MSBuild script for our CI process and in this script I use a MSBuild task to compile the solution:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MyOutPath>Output</MyOutPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<MSBuild
    Projects="MySolution.sln"
    Targets="Clean;Rebuild"
    Properties="OutputPath=$(MyOutPath)\%24(AssemblyName)">
</MSBuild>
```

I want the c# project files to use an output path like

- Output\MyAssemblyName1 for the project MyAssemblyName1
- Output\MyAssemblyName2 for the project MyAssemblyName2

The AssemblyName property is from the C# project file and I want it to be expanded in the OutputPath property when building the project.

Right now, %24(AssemblyName) just produce Output\$(AssemblyName) on the filesystem which is not what I want.

Not surprisingly, using $(AssemblyName) expands to nothing in the "parent" MSBuild file.

Is there any way to defer the resolution of the AssemblyName property later in the target project file?

Also, I do not want to modify the .csproj file as I want the least impact from the CI system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could import the `.csproj` project file directly into your MSBuild script using the [**Import** element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92x05xfs.aspx). This way you could reference the `AssemblyName` property directly:

```
<Import Project="MyProject.csproj" />
<Message Text="The assembly name is $(AssemblyName)" />
```

If you need to import the contents of a `.sln` solution file, first you'll have to [convert it to an MSBuild project file](http://www.sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,2a926fd2-70ce-4b95-a489-2d6aa24bc7da.aspx) by setting the `MSBuildEmitSolution` environment variable to `1` and run MSBuild on the solution file. This will generate a `MySolution.sln.proj` file, which you can then import into your script like described before:

```
<SetEnv Name="MSBuildEmitSolution" Value="1" />
<MSBuild Projects="MySolution.sln" Targets="Build" />
<Import Project="MySolution.sln.proj" />
```

Comment: Well, I have a solution referencing several project files and all the project files are not known in advance. Does Import support items?

Comment: Furthermore, I've got solutions that do not necessarily includes all the projects so I would have to parse the sln file for correct project files to process.

Comment: If you're using MSBuild 4.0, the [Import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92x05xfs.aspx) element actually supports wildcards, so you'll be able to say `<Import Project="SomePath\*.csproj" />` to import all the project files in a specific directory.

Comment: Still leaves with excluding some projects according to the content of the solution file.